# Swipe left right for poll

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a list of questions with `Ionic`/`Angular` and with a simple swipe to the left or right you can vote yes or no, including the `animation`. Not static.
`Tinder` might be a good example in this one.

I've researched on `Google` but I haven't found anything close to what I'm trying to achieve.

I know there's an `ion-list` with `ion-option-button` but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might probably missed that **Gestures and Events** category in the [ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipeRight/)? There are two directives which i think completely fit your needs...

```
<button on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()" class="button">Test</button>
<button on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" class="button">Test</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those but there's no animation when swiped (and if not fully swiped, snap right back). I could of course use `css3` but I think there must be an easier way in `Ionic`

Comment: [ionic slide box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) ??

Comment: But that's for a slider I think? I have a list of questions (below each other) and if I swipe left or right it either votes yes or no, and it disappears. Unless you think it's possible to do this with lots of slide boxes?

Comment: You can try to build your own directive and using this ionic slide box as a template.

Comment: I've used the box slide and it totally had what I needed

Comment: I am happy to hear that ;-)